# Creating Dual Line Graph in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I want to create a graph as shown in the figure. The Y axis is types of events and X axis is time. So I am tracking the which event has happened at which time. So the first line (red color) shows the intialization of an event and blue line denotes the same events with some delay. The yellow dots signifies the points and the green line highlights the distance between red and blue line.

[image]

I am able to have one line graph in Apache Superset, but have no clue on how to have 2 lines graphs in one.

Answer (score -3):

You can use a Dual line chart or a multi line chart. Refer to the following tutorial:-
https://docs.preset.io/docs/dual-chart

https://docs.preset.io/docs/multiple-line-chart

Comment: Both links return 404. This is why your response should not just be links. Include the actual answer on Stack Overflow.